# Candy XMPP Client Javascript Error

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to run candy XMPP client, but the debugger (firefox) says:

`SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Line 25 is this:

`view: { assets: '../res/' }`

For this javascript function (i don't know much about javascript)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Candy.init('http://cheesecakeproductions.com/http-bind/', {
            core: {
                // only set this to true if developing / debugging errors
                debug: true,
                // autojoin is a *required* parameter if you don't have a plugin (e.g. roomPanel) for it
                //   true
                //     -> fetch info from server (NOTE: does only work with openfire server)
                //   ['test@conference.example.com']
                //     -> array of rooms to join after connecting
                autojoin: ['gen1@conference.cheesecakeproductions.com' ] }, 
            },
            view: { assets: '../res/' }
        });
```

Comment: It looks like you have an extra `}` after `autojoin:` as well missing `})` to close `Candy.init(...,{`. See the [example on this page](http://candy-chat.github.io/candy/).

Comment: `view` should be a "sibling" of `core`, no? Currently, it is not. There are mismatched `)` and `}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are closing the argument list for `Candy.init` prematurely, after the `autojoin:` line.

You also appear to be missing the `})` that closes `Candy.init('...',{`.

I suggest:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    Candy.init('http://cheesecakeproductions.com/http-bind/', {
        core: {
            debug: true,
            autojoin: ['gen1@conference.cheesecakeproductions.com']
        },   /* Closes Core */
        view: {
            assets: '../res/'
        }    /* Closes View */
    });  /* Closes Candy.init */
});  /* Closes document ready */
```

Comment: Yes, things were out of order